# Size of binary for Apple Watch apps

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, watchos

I'm developing an iOS app with a corresponding watchOS app. The watchOS app is not required and the iOS app should still be accesable to people who doesn't have an Apple Watch.

My question is regarding the size of the app; the binary size. Does the people who needs the watchOS app and the people who doesn't download the same binary?

If this is the case, this means that for the non-watch users the download size will be unnecessary big, since it also contains the watchOS binary, right?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at Apple's [documentation](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/devbbdc5ce4f) on App thinning and Bitcode, it seems that they do quite a lot to ensure an elegant and small footprint for apps, including on demand resource download and architecture specific binaries.

That said, it seems that WatchOS components aren't included in this process.